# How to add a page to floating action button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a social Websters app as I have a another of pages on the bottom app bar i want to launch camera or gallery to add new post through floating action button.

Comment: Can you add more detail about your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the ImagePicker from Flutter Plugins.

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

```
onTap: (){
  ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou but is there a way to navigate to a new page? Coz the user has to post details along with image. Example: if the person is posting something on the shop page   then he has to enter certain details.

Comment: Sure just navigate, you can use multiple ways there. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation